# PHP echo changing text?

Tags: php, echo

I'm a beginner PHP programmer, and I was wondering what was wrong with my code.

Here is the small excerpt from the affected spot:

```
echo "<form action='?tab=4' name='toedit5' method='get'><input value='text' onblur='edit('toedit5')' /></form>";
```

In Chrome's Developer Tools, the `form` element totally disappears, and the `edit('toedit5')` becomes `edit(' toedit5')`.

The `edit()` function doesn't execute.

Is there anything wrong with this one line of code? Otherwise it is outside code messing with it. Sorry I didn't include it, but I don't know what to include. If you need more information, please tell me.

Thanks.

Comment: Looks like a malformed element.  You need to escape your quotes.

Comment: This is a plain `HTML` (& `javascript`) problem, nothing to do with PHP. Perform simple HTML validation on it...

Comment: Oh. Thanks. But I fixed that, and it ended up still not echoing the form element

Comment: Show us the actual generated html; not from the inspector, but the 'view source' information.

Comment: From the view source tool  I figured out that it showed the form element. Now I am thoroughly confused.

Comment: @Jon c.c Again, please show us the actual end result.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to escape your quotes *inside* your quoted echo'd statement, like this:

```
<?php
    echo "<form action='?tab=4' name='toedit5' method='get'>";
    echo "<input value='text' onblur='edit(\"toedit5\")' />"; // escaped..!
    echo "</form>";
?>
```

It helped me to think about it like this when I was starting out: how does your browser know if the second single quote in `onblur='edit('toedit5')'` is closing your `onblur` statement or  opening up the parameter? In this example, your browser will pair up the first 2 quotes it sees and assign that to the `onblur` attribute, i.e.: `onblur='edit('` only!

***Update 1:***

Using the code above, I inspected a quick PHP page I created in Chrome's developer tools and was able to see the following (form available for inspection):

[image: Screen shot of developer tools]

Comment: As I mentioned above, the form element is still not printing for some unknown reason.

Answer (score 4):

You really should use the more standard double quotes around the HTML properties and use single quotes around your string, with escaped single quotes within the javascript method calls.  Like this:

```
echo '<form action="?tab=4" name="toedit5" method="get"><input value="text" onblur="edit(\'toedit5\')" /></form>';
```